# How can I extract <p> tag's contents in table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First of all, my table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead-light border">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>difficulty</th>
            <th>goal</th>
            <th>recommended</th>
            <th>return</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chosen">
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
                <p>recommended2</p>
                <p>recommended3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That "recommended" column can have 1~3 <p> tags.
And, what I want to do is, extract strings between each <p> tag and then use it as id tag. like this:

in case that I extracted "recommended1", "recommended2", I want to do like this for example:

```
$('#recommended1').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
$('#recommended2').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
```

But the problem is, extracted strings are connected each other other like this > recommended1recommended2recommended3

my code is:

```
    $("#chosen").on("click", "tr td:not(:last-child)", function() {
        var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
        var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").find("p").text();
        var data=col3
        alert(data);
    });
```

alerted just for check.

Q1. How can I separate extracted strings?

Q2. How can I use extracted string as tag?

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only js for reach your goal, simple use `querySelectorAll` for find all `p` then you can use that in many ways, in my example i use `forEach` with `console.log` for print each of that.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table'); //select table
var AllP = table.querySelectorAll('p'); //select all p


AllP.forEach(function(p) {
  console.log(p); // all tag
  console.log(p.innerHTML); //just text
  console.log(' '); // space for better understanding
});
/*
You print one of the array like:
console.log(p[0]); choise index based on your choise
*/
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover" id='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead-light border">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>difficulty</th>
            <th>goal</th>
            <th>recommended</th>
            <th>return</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chosen">
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
                <p>recommended2</p>
                <p>recommended3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However if you want use **jquery**:

```js
var AllP = $('#table').find('p'); //select all p
$(AllP).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text()); //just text
  console.log(' '); // space for better understanding
});

/*
You print one of the array like:
console.log(p[0]); choise index based on your choise
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover" id='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead-light border">
            <th>name</th>
            <th>difficulty</th>
            <th>goal</th>
            <th>recommended</th>
            <th>return</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chosen">
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
                <p>recommended2</p>
                <p>recommended3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <p>recommended1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>return1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: really sorry... I forgot to comment because I was on moving thank you!

Comment: please flag answer with V :)